# is half-niqab allowed in islam?

Tags: hijab

is it okay to wear half-niqab? My friend says that you should either show the whole face or cover the whole face except eyes, but it is not okay to show forehead and eyebrows.

Comment: https://c8.alamy.com/comp/2BC99NH/muslim-girl-wearing-surgical-mask-for-protection-hijab-woman-take-a-mask-for-coronavirus-or-covid-19-epidemic-or-pandemic-2BC99NH.jpg ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a well-known difference of opinion in regard to the issue of covering the face. Some scholars hold that covering the face is obligatory for women in the presence of non-mahram men. Others hold that covering the face is recommended but not obligatory. Both positions are based on interpretations of the Qur'an and the Sunnah.

As for the half-niqab, its permissibility depends on one's position regarding covering the face:

- **For those who consider covering the face as obligatory**, wearing the half-niqab is not permissible, since it does not cover the upper half of the face, and therefore it's insufficient. Based on this interpretation, only the eyes may be left exposed, and the rest of the face needs to be covered.
- **For those who consider covering the face as recommended (but not required)**, the half-niqab is an acceptable form of covering/hijab, and is better than leaving the whole face uncovered.

In general, for an individual, it is better to be err on the side of caution, as the Prophet ﷺ says: "Leave that which makes you doubt for that which does not make you doubt. (Narrated by at-Tirmidhi and an-Nasa'i)"
Therefore, in most situations, wearing the full-niqab is preferable to wearing the half-niqab, and wearing the half-niqab is better than leaving the whole face uncovered.

However, it is also important not to be judgmental of other women who follow other valid interpretations, as difference of opinion allows for flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

if no niqab is allowed if no fitnah (trial or danger) is feared, then of course half niqaab is allowed.